# Is there a way to know or eventually know how much weapons Israel got from the U.S. in the future or present?

Tags: united-states, israel

> The big picture: Israel is the largest recipient of U.S. foreign
> military financing, with most of that aid coming in the form of
> weapons grants. "I think it's a safe assumption to say that U.S.
> weapons are being used extensively in the current Israeli operations
> in Gaza," Elias Yousif, a U.S. arms transfer expert at the Stimson
> Center, told Time earlier this month.
>
> The U.S. has provided Israel with at least sixteen types of weapons in 2023, including missiles and aircraft, **though the exact
> numbers and types of weapons have not been made public.**

https://www.axios.com/2023/11/29/us-weapons-provided-israel-aircraft-missiles-bombs

Is there a way to know or eventually know how much weapons Israel got from the U.S. in the future or present? The article says that the numbers and types of weapons the U.S. provided in 2023 was not made public, but I am wondering if there are mechanisms that will ensure that the public knows or eventually knows about it and there's a paper trail that will be made available when the public inquires or when it can inquire.

Comment: What research have you done? If you just put 'military aid by US to Israel' into a search engine tons of results pop up.

Comment: [45 US planes delivered 1,000 tons of armaments to Israel since 'Iron Swords' war began](https://allisrael.com/45-us-planes-brought-1-000-tons-of-armaments-to-israel-since-the-start-of-iron-swords)